# count posts one category in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I have problems with count posts a cateory and show them. 
I want show categories in sidbar and count of them base on posts.

for example.

- num=count of posts that have medical is 8
- medical=8

My post table is "ebooks"
My category table is "categories"

My model is:

```
    public function count_item(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->join('ebooks', 'categories.cat_id = ebooks.cat_id');
    $this->db->where(array('ebooks.cat_id !=' => null, 'categories.cat_id != ' => NULL));
    $this->db->group_by(array('categories.cat_id', 'categories.name'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

my conroller is:

```
  public function posts() {

    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts();
    $data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->count_item();

    $this->load->view('inc/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/posts', $data);
    $this->load->view('inc/footer');

}
```

my view is:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><?php 
                            echo $category['name']; 
                            ?><span class="badge" style="float: left">14</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <center><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">more details</a></center>
                </div>
```

I want show number of posts based one a categories here:
{HERE}

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$this->db->select('categories.name as categories_name, COUNT(ebooks.cat_id) as categories_count');
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->join('ebooks', 'categories.cat_id = ebooks.cat_id');
$this->db->where(array('ebooks.cat_id !=' => null, 'categories.cat_id != ' => NULL));
$this->db->group_by('ebooks.cat_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```